# $_SESSION from core php to YII2

Tags: php, apache, session, yii2

We have a project in core PHP. Now we want to convert one of it's module to YII2.

So my approach is like this:-

As per our old code, when user submit string for search, then we get all data in core php, And make a unique URL of that. And after we redirect control to this url. this unique URL is handled by .htaccess file. further processing is running by core PHP file (Which is in .htaccess file).

Now we want to convert module after .htaccess processing.
Before URL making everything works fine. URL is creating fine and we are saving some use full info in session and and redirecting control to yii2 controller. Now our problem is how we get data there?
We added important data in session but unable to get data there using $_SESSION.
We cant change the URL.
We cant use POST method.
So how?

Example:-

User search

```
  ' India gate,new delhi, india'
```

So we are making this type of url

```
  /india/new-delhi/india-gate
```

Now .htaccess url is like this

```
  RewriteRule ^india(.*)/$ /pages/india/process.php
```

We made a controller in YII2 and changed .htaccess url like this

```
 RewriteRule ^india(.*)/$ /web/index.php?r=site/india [NC]
```

Page is redirected, but problem is how we get core php data on this YII2 framework? Like $_SESSION data and another data

Comment: kindly refer this for session handling: http://www.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework2/session-handling-in-yii-framework-2-0/ and this: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-session.html

Comment: I tried this Yii::$app->session, But its not showing core PHP session data.

Comment: you can turn on pretty url to remove `?r=site/india`.

Comment: first you have to set the session using yii2 then you can get data from it.

Comment: can i set yii2 session in core PHP? And it's old code, We dont want to modify that, That's why we are planning to change only view via YII2.

Comment: Sorry, But URL is all ready is handled by us using .htaccess file RewriteRule ^india(.*)/$ /web/index.php?r=site/india [NC]

Comment: as long as i know it's not possible or i don't know how to.

Answer (score 1):

I understand, you have two php application - old one, where you set some data, and a new one with Yii2, where you need to read that data. 
The session mechanism will not allow you to share one session between two different applications, but you can use some middleware - say, a memcache server: you'll write data into memcache from first app, and then you'll read it from yii.

Comment: Sorry, Don't know too much about this (memcache), But i will try.